# Blazor WASM Data Validation security

Tags: blazor

In a classic website with ASP.NET + JavaScript, we need to validate data for the client & server because javascript could be disabled in the browser, is this something i should worry about in case of blazor(WASM) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

It does not matter what the front-end framework is... if it's Blazor WASM, React, vanilla-JS, Angular, etc... your server should **always** validate input.